# How do you detect client side web browser?

Tags: html, safari

I'm trying to execute special behavior dependent on which web browser is being used.
I'd prefer a solution in HTML, but a scripting language would be fine too.

The special behavior is pretty minimal and only for safari users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigator object in javascript will do that for you.

Here ya go:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I'm aware of that only uses HTML code and no JS is conditional comments. It'll be applied by IE9 and below OR IE10+ and non-IE browsers.

In CSS, prefix vendors (like `-webkit-some-experimental-property`) are there for still experimental properties and non-standard ones.

As a general advice: don't ever try to detect browsers with JS or server-side or one of them will bite you back sooner or later. Explain what your problem really is and you'll probably learn how to do it with another method.